# How to iterate through bucket in LinkedHashMap?

Tags: java, arraylist, linkedhashmap

I would like to iterate through all the values in every bucket in the following linkedhashmap

```
LinkedHashMap<String, Integer> test
```

in order to get to an arraylist of the following type

```
List<Set<Integer>>
```

So that all the integers in the same bucket can be found in the same set inside the arraylist eventually. What's the best way of doing this?

Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: Can't be done. `LinkedHashMap` doesn't expose its implementation.

Comment: What about if I were to use a HashMap instead?

Comment: @shmosel, if we are able to access the hashcode of the key, we will know which value go in which bucket, right?

Comment: @Ringstaartmaki Same thing.

Comment: @mettleap Sure, you can reproduce the algorithm from the source code. But you're not really getting the info from the map. And it's an implementation detail that's subject to change at any time in any environment. I would question why OP would need this in the first place.

Comment: I'm trying to fit LSH (Locality-Senstive Hashing) for Minhash Signatures inside an existing framework that checks similarities between documents using a List<Set<Integer>>. [link](http://infolab.stanford.edu/~ullman/mmds/ch3.pdf)   If you know an alternative way of doing so, let me know!  Thank you for your answers.

Comment: @mettleap you can query the hash code of the keys, that's no problem. But the mapping between the hash code and the actual bucket is a function over the map's current capacity (array length) and an implementation dependent algorithm, which may change in every version (and has already changed in the past).

Comment: @Ringstaartmaki being in the same bucket is not a sign of having a similarity, not even remotely. In fact, it's the opposite, the implementors do their best to avoid objects with similarities to end up in the same bucket. The strings `" !!!!\"xurlls"`, `"f5a5a608"`, `""`, and `"\4\32\0\23\35\30\4"` have the same hash code, so what does it mean?